# deciding if a number is perfect or prime

Tags: c++, numbers, primes, modulus, perfect-numbers

the problem is :
"Write a function to find out if a number is a prime or perfect number."

so far i have worked on the perfect part first and this is what i have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool perfectNumber(int);
int main()
{
 int number;

 cout<<"Please enter number:\n";
 cin>>number;
 bool perfectNumber(number);

 return 0;
}
bool perfectNumber(int number)
{
 int i;

 int sum=0;
 for(i=1;i<=number/2;i++)
 {
  if(number%i==0)
  {
   sum+=i;
  }
 }
 if (sum==number)
  return i;
 else
  return 0;
}
```

HOWEVER, there seems to be errors on this code. 
I have looked over the book but nothing talks about this topic.
i would like to get advice on how to fix this code.

thanks!

Comment: % means remainder of number/i as 4%2=0

Comment: Sounds like one of Project Euler's. But maybe it's just me ;)

Comment: What errors are you getting. Looking at the code sample you are defining perfectNumber(int) as a bool but you are returning an int.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko: There's nothing wrong with that. The problem is in line 10 (see Answer from James McNellis).

Answer (score 7):

```
bool perfectNumber(number);
```

This does not call the `perfectNumber` function; it declares a local variable named `perfectNumber` of type `bool` and initializes it with the value of `number` converted to type `bool`.

In order to call the `perfectNumber` function, you need to use something along the lines of:

```
bool result = perfectNumber(number);
```

or:

```
bool result(perfectNumber(number));
```

On another note:  if you are going to read input from a stream (e.g. `cin>>number`), you must check to be sure that the extraction of the value from the stream succeeded.  As it is now, if you typed in `asdf`, the extraction would fail and `number` would be left uninitialized.  The best way to check whether an extraction succeeds is simply to test the state of the stream:

```
if (cin >> number) {
    bool result = perfectNumber(number);
}
else {
    // input operation failed; handle the error as appropriate
}
```

You can learn more about how the stream error states are set and reset in [Semantics of flags on `basic_ios`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258887/semantics-of-flags-on-basic-ios).  You should also consult [a good, introductory-level C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for more stream-use best practices.

Answer (score 1):

```
void primenum(long double x) {
    bool prime = true; 
    int number2;
    number2 = (int) floor(sqrt(x));// Calculates the square-root of 'x'

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= number2; j++) {
            if (i != j && i % j == 0) {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime) {
            cout << " " << i << " ";
            c += 1;
        }
        prime = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: bool prime = true; // Calculates the square-root of 'x'  Really? it's also important to place comments correctly.

Comment: This is so wrong. If you are testing if x is prime, get rid of the outer loop. If you are testing for all primes in [1,x] then the bound on the inner loop should be sqrt(i) not sqrt(x). And in that case this is a ridiculously inefficient way to test for primes in that range. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes for a much better method.

Answer (score 1):

```
 bool isPerfect(  int number){
     int i;
     int sum=0;
     for(i=1;i<number ;i++){
         if(number %i == 0){
             cout<<"  " << i ;
             sum+=i;
         }
     }

     if (sum == number){
         cout<<"\n \t\t THIS NUMBER  >>>  "<<  number <<"   IS    PERFECT \n\n";
         return i;
     }else if (sum |= number) {
               cout<<"\nThis number >>> " <<  number <<"   IS  NOT  PERFECT \n\n";
               return 0;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#pragma hdrstop

#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------


bool is_prim(int nr)
{

    for (int i = 2; i < nr-1; i++) {

    if (nr%i==0) return false;

    }

    return true;

}

bool is_ptr(int nr)
{
    int sum=0;

    for (int i = 1; i < nr; i++) {

    if (nr%i==0) {
        sum=sum+i;
    }

    }

    if (sum==nr) { return true;

    }
    else return false;
}
#pragma argsused
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int numar;

    printf ("Number=");scanf("%d",&numar);
    if (is_prim(numar)==true) { printf("The number is prime");

    }
    else printf("The number is not prime");

    if (is_ptr(numar)==true) { printf(" The number is perfect");

    }
    else printf(" The number is not perfect");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is_ptr returns false or true for a perfect number and is_prim returns true or false for a prime number

Comment: *Please* format your code. Didn't you look at the preview and notice "this is unreadable" before posting the answer? In the editor, select the source code, then click the `101010` button.

Comment: @jalf `101010` means `fine` ? I didn't know :-)

Comment: funny. ;) btw, to avoid confusion if others read this, the `{ }` button *used* to show something like `10010` instead.