# Prime-testing program not working

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, primes

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Enter a number." << endl;
    cin >> x;
    int y = 1;
    int i = 0;
    while (i == 0 && y < sqrtf(x))
    {
        if (fmodf(x,y) == 0)
        {
            i = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            i = 0;
        }
        y++;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        cout << "Your number is prime." << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Your number is composite." << endl;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is a code I created to test for primes. After sorting out several debugging issues I was able to run it.

It opened the command window, read 'Enter a number' and closed itself the second I entered a number.

Help?

Comment: Why are you using `fmodf` for that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

- close the `while` loop in the correct place
- change the `if (i == 1)` condition (`i==1` means `x` is divisible by some `y`)
- start with `y = 2` (every number is divisible by one)
- **include** `sqrtf(x)` in the loop (`y <= sqrtf(x)` or 15, 25, 35... are primes).

So:

```
int main()
{
  int x;
  cout << "Enter a number." << endl;
  cin >> x;

  int y = 2;  // <-- changed
  int i = 0;

  while (i == 0 && y <= sqrtf(x))  // <-- changed
  {
    if (fmodf(x,y) == 0)
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }

    y++;
  }  // <-- moved here

  if (i == 0)  // <-- changed
  {
    cout << "Your number is prime." << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Your number is composite." << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

works (more or less...).

Anyway:

- don't use `using namespace std;` ([Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3235496))
- `\n` should be your default (["\n" or '\n' or std::endl to std::cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8311058/3235496))
- `y` and `x` are integers so you can use `%` instead of `fmodf`
- avoid [premature pessimization](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/13/gotw-2-solution-temporary-objects/): prefer preincrement, only use postincrement if you're going to use the original value
- `else { i = 0; }` is superfluous
- you can change `y < sqrtf(x)` with `y * y <= x` (and you don't need `math.h` anymore) or find square root of number **then** start the loop

Somewhat better (but far from perfect):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x;
  std::cout << "Enter a number.\n";
  std::cin >> x;

  int square_root = std::sqrt(x);
  int y = 2;
  int i = 0;
  while (i == 0 && y <= square_root)
  {
    if (x % y == 0)
      i = 1;

    ++y;
  }

  if (i == 0)
    std::cout << "Your number is prime.\n";
  else
    std::cout << "Your number is composite.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Now:

- input validation, i.e. check for bad input values ([How to check if input is numeric in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5655142/3235496))
- special cases checking ([is the number one a prime number?](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumber.html))
- a `bool` would express your intentions better than `int i`;
- improve the algorithm ([Determining if a number is prime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4424374/3235496), [Which is the fastest algorithm to find prime numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/453793/3235496), [Primality tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test))

Comment: That's very useful. But how do I stop it from closing the moment it outputs? Is there a setting for that? (I use Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express)