# Prime numbers c++

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int n, liczba;

int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> liczba;
        if (liczba < 2) {
            cout << "NIE" << endl;
        } else if (liczba == 2) {
            cout << "TAK" << endl;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i < liczba; i++) {
            if (liczba % i == 0) {
                cout << "NIE" << endl;
                break;
            } else if (liczba % i != 0) {
                cout << "TAK" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program is supposed to write yes `"TAK"` or no `"NIE"` whether the number you input is prime or isn't. Variable `n` is the number of numbers you want to input into program, and `liczba` is the number you want to check if it's prime or not. It seems to work fine expect one significant thing. If I input number 9 it says yes `"TAK"` instead of no `"NIE"`.. I discovered that this happens to numbers: `9,27,45,63,81` and so on.. if I add `18` starting from `9` it will happen every time.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You have not used a flag and thus it says NIE after first check

Comment: @Konradek I don't approve of your logic.

Comment: Potentially useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Comment: @Vaibhav Bajaj can u explain a little simplier? I dont understand you, im beginner at c++, I dont know what flag is.. :/

Comment: All your for loop is doing is checking if the number is odd. (It always breaks out of the first iteration of the loop)

Comment: @Konradek If you're a beginner a probably better strategy to learn c++ is to work through a textbook, rather than asking confused question at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining if a number is prime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424374/determining-if-a-number-is-prime)

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question is clear enough and even has example code showing OP *tried* to solve the problem on his own.

Comment: @JesperJuhl may be, because he is using Polish variable names...

Answer (score 3):

You're `break`ing on BOTH sides of your `if()` test. Effectly you'll only ever test one divisor:

e.g. liczba = 9

```
1. if (liczba % 2 == 0) -> if (9 % 2 == 0) -> if (1 == 0) -> false
2. ...jump to else
3. if (liczba % 2 != 0) -> if (9 % 2 != 0) -> if (1 != 0) -> TRUE
4. spit out 'tak' and break out of the loop
```

You cannot break out of the loop "early" if you get a remainder. That means the divisor you tested is **NOT** a factor of the number. You can only break early if you DO get a remainder of `0`, which means the number's not prime - it's composite.

Comment: Thanks for help, to all of You guys! :) It is brighter to me now ;) How to start my adventure with C++? I have book but I would rather do something interactive like Codecademy? I know that there is no course on Codecademy but I just gave an example. I know it may sound rash or reckless but I've read couple of pages of this book (about 120 I guess) and I would code something myself rather than only acquire knowledge without practical use. What do You think?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

> All prime numbers (except 2 and 3) can be expressed in the form `6k+1`
>   or `6k-1`, where k is a positive whole number.

Therefore, This should work:

```
bool IsPrime( int number )
{

 if ( ( (!(number & 1)) && number != 2 ) || (number < 2) || (number % 3 == 0 && number != 3) )
      return (false);

 for( int k = 1; 36*k*k-12*k < number;++k)
     if ( (number % (6*k+1) == 0) || (number % (6*k-1) == 0) )
         return (false);
     return true;
}
```

Taken from [**Determining if a number is prime**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424374/determining-if-a-number-is-prime).

Comment: If it is, then he could use other answers. Yours looks fine right?

Comment: I think its okayish... Thanks for your answer. I would like to use it as it sure will greatly improve efficiency. Currently I scanned till square root N.

Comment: and of cousre, there's NO point in scanning even numbers, just start testing at 3 and do `i=i+2`.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah, that too halved time taken.

Answer (score 1):

You have not used a flag and thus it says `NIE` after first check. Also, you are missing an else statement.
Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int n,liczba;
int main()
{
    cin >> n; //
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>liczba;
            if (liczba < 2)
                {
                cout << "NIE" << endl;
                }
            else if (liczba == 2)
            {
                cout << "TAK" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                bool isPrime = true;
                for (int i=2;i<liczba;i++)
                {

                    if (liczba % i == 0)
                        {
                            isPrime = false;
                            break;
                        } 
                }
                if(isPrime)
                    cout<<"TAK";
                else
                    cout<<"NIE";
            }

        }
    return 0;
}
```

Currently, if you input 7, It will check if `7 % 2 == 0`. Since it is not, it will print "NIE" and break out of the loop.