# Converting strings to sum of ASCII values of all characters and checking for primes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function to do these things:

- read a file
- for each line, add all ASCII values of every character
- check if sum of those values is a prime number
- return how many prime numbers were in file

Here are the functions:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int n) {
    if (n < 2) return false;
    for (int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}

int checkFile () {
    ifstream napis("data.txt");
    string line;
    int primesCount = 0;

    while (napis.is_open() && getline(napis, line)) {
        int lineLen = line.length();
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lineLen; i++) {
            sum += (int)line[i];
        }

        if (isPrime(sum)) primesCount++;
    }

    return primesCount;
}
```

Each line in file is a string with only capital letters, for example `AQUALFJMAGDDSNO`

I have a file of 1000 lines like that above, and I know there are `122` prime numbers, but this function returns `153`.

I know there are many other ways to to this and I've found solutions on the internet, but why isn't this function working properly?

Comment: You're probably not accounting for the newline character. Also, it'd be helpful if you were able to provide a line that you know should not be counted as prime but is.

Comment: @krzaq What newline character?  `getline` is going to discard it.

Comment: @NathanOliver, you're right, my bad. The point about a testcase stands.

Comment: There may be an issue with how you solve primes.  What happens if you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14418599/4342498) way?

Comment: @krzaq I don't know which lines are wrongly calculated, I would have to test them out manually.

Comment: @KrzysztofKraszewski well then, go ahead :)

Comment: @NathanOliver I used the function you linked and it gives the same result unfortunately.

Comment: @krzaq I don't think it's very efficient to test 1000 lines it would take me a very long time. Or maybe you have some quicker solution in mind?