# Performance when reaching 65535 jumps wildly compared to other input

Tags: c++, performance

Here's some code below to get the next prime number based on the input. I'm measuring as well how long it takes in nanoseconds for the operation to complete.

I am using C++ in Visual Studio 2017 (Community edition). My results from some numbers I input are from 300 nanoseconds for small numbers (1-100) to 800 nanoseconds (1,000,000,000 and higher). However, if I input 65535, I get 97767 nanoseconds. But when I input 65533, it's 438 nanoseconds, and when I input 65539, it's 487 nanoseconds.

My question is: why does 65535 take a larger time to compute, but for other number above or below it, it's significantly lower?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

bool isPrime(int num)
{
    int divisor = 3;
    while (divisor != INT_MAX)
    {
        if (divisor % 2 == 0)
        {
            divisor++;
        }
        if (num % divisor == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        divisor += 2;
    }
    return false;
}
int findNextPrime(int num) 
{
    while (num != INT_MAX) 
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0) 
        {
            num++;
        }
        else 
        {
            num += 2;
        }

        if (isPrime(num))
        {
            return num;
        }
        else
        {
            num++;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int candidatePrime;
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> candidatePrime;
    const auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    const int nextPrime = findNextPrime(candidatePrime);
    const auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << nextPrime << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count()
        << " nanoseconds" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> str;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, make sure you are timing an optimized build. Secondly, use a profiler to see where and how time is spent.

Answer (score 3):

First of all your `bool isPrime(int num)` dose not check if a number is prime or not. Try it with 25 for example. You should first try to fix that. Also have a look here [Determining if a number is prime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424374/determining-if-a-number-is-prime?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But to answer your question:
When you input 65533, you call **is_prime** with 65535 which is divisible by 3, so your `while (divisor != INT_MAX)` loop will only run 1 time.

When you input 65535, you call **is_prime** with 65537 which is a prime number, so your `while (divisor != INT_MAX)` loop will run ~32767 times.

It's only normal that for prime numbers your function will take longer to run.