# "An access violation (Segmentation Fault) raised in your program."

Tags: c++, dev-c++

My C++ program compiles and works up until I call this function from main():

```
int uword(){fstream infile("numbers.txt");
fstream exfile("wordlist.txt");
string numb[numoflines];
string lines[numoflines];  
number = 1; 
line = 1;  
for(int i=0;i<numofline;++i)
    {
    getline (infile,number);
    numb[i] = number; //I think this is causing the problem
    getline (exfile,line);
    lines[i] = line; //This too
    }
infile.close();
exfile.close();    
string yourword;
```

Something here causes it to crash, in the debug it pops up with "An access violation (Segmentation Fault) raised in your program."

EDIT: My mistake was using !infile.eof in the for loop.

Comment: Your input loop is incorrect.  GMan gave a good explanation of how to properly handle input in [an answer to one of the C++ FAQ questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258887/semantics-of-flags-on-basic-ios/4259111#4259111).

Comment: Changing !infile.eof() to i<=numoflines (Which should do the same thing) still gives me the error. I think that is what you meant by your reference.

Comment: Do you mean i<numoflines (not i <= numoflines?) - you're still overrunning the buffer by one line.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, and when I changed it in my code it works now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer, but I believe it's a good one...

**Use The Debugger!** GDB should suspend at the **exact line** when the segmentation fault happens, thus giving you a very good hint about what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

The `getline` function does not work the way you think it works.

Also, there could be more than `numoflines` lines in `infile`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the proper use of 'getline'? numoflines was calculated previously by how many lines were in the file.

Comment: @Mark : See `man 3 getline`. It's designed for use with C `FILE*` handles, and you're trying to use it here with an `fstream`.  You should do `infile >> number` to use a C++-style `ifstream`.

Comment: I am using getline becuase it seems to work for this purpose. infile >> number would just write the whole file to number right?