# Accessing Vectors In C++

Tags: c++, vector

I wrote a simple program that accesses a file called "input.txt" and pushes its contents into a vector of the string type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream input;
    input.open("input.txt");
    string s;
    input >> s;
    while (!input.eof())
    {
        cout << s <<endl;
        input >> s;
        vector<string> v;
        v.push_back(s);
    }
    input.close();

}
```

I know this isn't the best way to do this but is there a way that I can then access this vector and use it for an equation? Say if I wanted to add all the elements of the vector together and find the sum?

Comment: Your code is incorrect. The loop in particular.

Comment: See this for why your loop is wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258887/semantics-of-flags-on-basic-ios

Comment: What do you mean by the "sum" of the strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, here's a much cleaner version of the code you've just written:

```
ifstream input("input.txt");
string s;
while (input >> s) {
    cout << s << endl;
    vector<string> elems;
    elems.push_back(s);
}
```

This uses `ifstream` instead of `fstream`, which seems appropriate here since you aren't using the write facilities of `fstream`.  It also combines the read logic with the loop condition, simplifying the logic for when to continue.

One thing that seems weird with this code is that you've scoped the `vector` so that it only lives for one loop iteration.  Consequently, every iteration, you lose all your old `vector` contents.  Moving this out of the loop would probably fix this:

```
ifstream input("input.txt");
vector<string> elems;

string s;
while (input >> s) {
    cout << s << endl;
    elems.push_back(s);
}
```

Finally, if you want to loop over the elements of the `vector` adding them together, you probably don't want to be reading the file as strings, but rather as `int`s or `double`s.  This saves you the hassle of having to convert the values later.  For example:

```
ifstream input("input.txt");
vector<double> elems;

double s;
while (input >> s) {
    cout << s << endl;
    elems.push_back(s);
}
```

Now, you can add all the values together like this:

```
double total = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < elems.size(); ++i)
    total += elems[i];
```

Or, even better, you can add everything together using the `accumulate` algorithm from `<numeric>`:

```
double total = accumulate(elems.begin(), elems.end(), 0.0);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for helping me out and running through my code, I'm going to try this right now.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is incorrect. What you probably meant is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream input("input.txt");
    string s;
    vector<string> v;
    while (input >> s)
    {
        cout << s <<endl;
        v.push_back(s);
    }
}
```

Also, here's another way of doing the same thing:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

struct ShowAndCopy {
    const std::string& operator()(const std::string& s) const {
        std::cout << s;
        return s;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("input.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(input),
                   std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                   std::back_inserter(v),
                   ShowAndCopy());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can iterate over the contents of the vector of strings, converting the values to an integer or floating point value and summing them.