# Terminating With Whitespace

Tags: c++

Instead of writing code like this

```
while (getline(cin, inputWord))
{
   if (inputWord.empty() || inputWord == " " || inputWord == "  " || inputWord == "   ")return 0;
}
```

How can I get the user to terminate the program regardless of how many whitespaces are present?

Comment: Does `cin.ignore()` do it for you?

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876959/ignore-spaces-using-getline-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient way to check if std::string has only spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444842/efficient-way-to-check-if-stdstring-has-only-spaces)

Comment: @Nabla I've tried that, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3200730 Then you should ask about why this answer does not work for you instead of asking nearly the same again. The answer provided there is probably correct, seeing it is highly upvoted, so probably you are doing something wrong or missed something. Please post the full code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own function that counts spaces:

```
int countWhiteSpaces(string input)
{
    // You do it :) Hint: a 'for' loop might do
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
while (getline(cin, inputWord))
{
   if (inputWord.empty() || countWhiteSpaces(inputWord) > 0)
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: It took me a few moments to catch what to do, but I pieced it together. Thank you, this was very useful :)

Comment: You're welcome! Just remember: when you see a problem that's too big for you to solve, try to see if there's a sub-problem that's easier to solve, and then generalize the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
while (getline(cin, inputWord))
{
    if(inputWord.find_first_not_of(' ') == std::string::npos) // all spaces
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 No, it's not enough. I just tested it.

Comment: I've tried using that, and when there's a space it doesn't terminate the program

Comment: @user3200730 How did you terminate the program?

Comment: I haven't figured out a way to do that without using the tedious task I presented above.

Comment: @user3200730 `return 0` will terminate the program. See updated.

Comment: Oh it was because I was typing it in as != instead of using  ==... it does work.