# How to check cin is end of file?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    if (cin)
    {
        (...)
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "No Data!!!" << endl;
    }
}
```

I want to check if the input has any data, but the error message won't be displayed even if I only input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> at the beginning.

Comment: I don't want to read in from cin at the beginning, as the first entry might be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cin.eof() functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939251/cin-eof-functionality)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [checking data availability before calling std::getline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317740/checking-data-availability-before-calling-stdgetline)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you attempted to read, the stream won't know whether there is any useful data. At the very least you'll need to look at the first character, e.g., using

```
if (std::cin.peek() != std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
    // do something with the potentially present input.
}
else {
    // fail
}
```

More likely you'll depend on some non-space data to be available. If so, you could see if there is something other than space in the file:

```
if (!(std::cin >> std::ws).eof())
  ...
```

The *manipulator* `std::ws` will skip leading whitespace. It will stop when either a non-whitespace character or the end of file is reached. If the end of file is reached, `std::cin.eof()` will be `true`.

In general, I wouldn't bother but rather try to read the first item. If nothing at all is read it would still be viable to fail:

```
bool hasData = false;
while (std::cin >> some >> data) {
    hasData = true;
    // do something with the input
}
if (!hasData) {
    // report that there was no data at all
}
```

The no data case may be implicitly testable, e.g., by looking at the size of a read data structure.