# C++ Pointer Assignment in custom class constructor

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

So I have a custom class 'Book' that has a bunch of member variables, amongst which are a vector of another custom class called 'Review' and a pointer to point at that vector as I need to pass that around through function calls in a driver program. The driver program reads the details of the each book (such as title, author, publish date etc.) from a text file and inserts into a temporary 'Book' object which it then adds onto a vector of Books maintained by the driver program. Here is the code for reading from the file:

```
ifstream file("books.txt");
string line;
if(file.is_open())
{
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        Book buffBook;
        getline(file, line);
        buffBook.setTitle(line);
        getline(file, line);
        buffBook.setAuthor(line);
        getline(file, line);
        buffBook.setPubDate(line);
        getline(file, line);
        buffBook.setIsbn(line);
        getline(file, line);
        buffBook.setCategory(line);
        getline(file, line);
        buffBook.setFormat(line);
        getline(file, line);
        buffBook.setSynopsis(line);
        vectBooks.push_back(buffBook);
    }
}

else
    cout<<"File not found(1)!"<<endl;

file.close();
```

This is running inside a int main() function.
One of the functions of the driver program is to add a review, which takes in data from the user and inserts it into a temporary 'Review' object. That object is then passed onto to be inserted in to the vector of reviews for the corresponding book. Here is the code for the **addReview()** function:

```
void addReview()
{
    string name = "";
    string title;
    Book rTemp;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Which book would you like to rate (Title)?: ";
    getline(cin, name);
    name = toLow(name);
    Review r;
    string re, user;
    int ra;
    cout<<"Username (Full Name): ";
    getline(cin, user);
    string fname = user.substr(0, user.find_first_of(' '));
    string lname = user.substr( user.find_first_of(' ') + 1, user.size());
    r.setUsrFName(fname);
    r.setUsrLName(lname);
    cout<<"Enter rating (1-5):";
    cin>>ra;
    r.setRating(ra);
    cout<<"Enter a short textual review: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, re);
    r.setReview(re);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vectBooks.size(); i++)
    {
         title = toLow(vectBooks[i].getTitle());
         if(title.find(name) != string::npos)
         {
             vectBooks[i].getReviews()->push_back(r);
         }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is if i add a review, it adds it for all the books. In other words, when I fetch the book info for any book, the review shows on all the books. I assume this is a problem with the pointer as it seems like all the reviews are getting stored in the same vector. I am not sure where I am messing up but I have a feeling it's with the pointer some where. Any help is appreciated.

Thank You

***UPDATE***

The point to the title of this problem is that I am doing the assignment of the pointer to the vector of Reviews in the constructor of the Book class, of which those 2 are member variables. Code as follows for constructor:

```
Book::Book()
{
    pointRev = &vectReviews;
}
```

***UPDATE 2***

Here is the code for the Book Class and supporting classes:

book.h

```
#ifndef BOOK_H_
#define BOOK_H_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "review.h"

using namespace std;

class Book
{
private:
    string title;
    string author;
    string pubDate;
    string isbn;
    string category;
    string format;
    string synopsis;
    vector<Review> vectReviews;
    vector<Review>* pointRev;
public:
    Book::Book() : pointRev(&vectReviews) {};
    string getAuthor() const;
    string getCategory() const;
    string getFormat() const;
    string getIsbn() const;
    string getPubDate() const;
    string getSynopsis() const;
    string getTitle() const;
    vector<Review>* getReviews();
    void setAuthor(string author);
    void setCategory(string category);
    void setFormat(string format);
    void setIsbn(string isbn);
    void setPubDate(string pubDate);
    void setSynopsis(string synopsis);
    void setTitle(string title);

    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Book& book);
    vector<Review> *getPointRev() const;
    vector<Review> getVectReviews() const;
    void setPointRev(vector<Review> *pointRev);
    void setVectReviews(vector<Review> vectReviews);


};

#endif /* BOOK_H_ */
```

**book. cpp**

```
#include "book.h"
string Book::getAuthor() const
{
    return author;
}

string Book::getCategory() const
{
    return category;
}

string Book::getFormat() const
{
    return format;
}

string Book::getIsbn() const
{
    return isbn;
}

string Book::getPubDate() const
{
    return pubDate;
}

string Book::getSynopsis() const
{
    return synopsis;
}

string Book::getTitle() const
{
    return title;
}

void Book::setAuthor(string author)
{
    this->author = author;
}

void Book::setCategory(string category)
{
    this->category = category;
}

void Book::setFormat(string format)
{
    this->format = format;
}

void Book::setIsbn(string isbn)
{
    this->isbn = isbn;
}

void Book::setPubDate(string pubDate)
{
    this->pubDate = pubDate;
}

void Book::setSynopsis(string synopsis)
{
    this->synopsis = synopsis;
}

void Book::setTitle(string title)
{
    this->title = title;
}

vector<Review> *Book::getPointRev() const
{
    return pointRev;
}

vector<Review> Book::getVectReviews() const
{
    return vectReviews;
}

void Book::setPointRev(vector<Review> *pointRev)
{
    this->pointRev = pointRev;
}

void Book::setVectReviews(vector<Review> vectReviews)
{
    this->vectReviews = vectReviews;
}

vector<Review>* Book::getReviews()
{
    return pointRev;
}


ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, Book& book)
{
    out<<"\nTitle: "<<book.getTitle()<<endl;
    out<<"Author: "<<book.getAuthor()<<endl;
    out<<"Publish Date: "<<book.getPubDate()<<endl;
    out<<"ISBN: "<<book.getIsbn()<<endl;
    out<<"Category: "<<book.getCategory()<<endl;
    out<<"Format: "<<book.getFormat()<<endl;
    out<<"Synopsis: "<<book.getSynopsis()<<endl;
    cout<<"\n--- Reviews ---"<<endl;
//  vector<Review>* revs = book.getReviews();
    for(unsigned int h = 0; h < book.getReviews()->size(); h++)
    {
        cout<<"Review by: "<<book.getReviews()->at(h).getUsrFName()<<" "<<book.getReviews()->at(h).getUsrLName()<<endl;
        cout<<"Rating: "<<book.getReviews()->at(h).getRating()<<endl;
        cout<<"Review: "<<book.getReviews()->at(h).getReview()<<endl;
    }

    return out;
}
```

**review.h**

```
#ifndef REVIEW_H_
#define REVIEW_H_

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Review
{
private:
    int rating;
    string review;
    string usrFName;
    string usrLName;
public:
    int getRating() const;
    string getReview() const;
    void setRating(int rating);
    void setReview(string review);
    string getUsrFName() const;
    string getUsrLName() const;
    void setUsrFName(string usrFName);
    void setUsrLName(string usrLName);
};

#endif /* REVIEW_H_ */
```

**review.cpp**

```
#include "review.h"



int Review::getRating() const
{
    return rating;
}

string Review::getReview() const
{
    return review;
}


void Review::setRating(int rating)
{
    this->rating = rating;
}

string Review::getUsrFName() const
{
    return usrFName;
}

string Review::getUsrLName() const
{
    return usrLName;
}

void Review::setUsrFName(string usrFName)
{
    this->usrFName = usrFName;
}

void Review::setUsrLName(string usrLName)
{
    this->usrLName = usrLName;
}

void Review::setReview(string review)
{
    this->review = review;
}
```

Comment: `while (!file.eof())` is not the correct way to write an input loop.  For the correct way, see GMan's answer to [one of the Stack Overflow C++ FAQ questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258887/semantics-of-flags-on-basic-ios/4259111#4259111).

Comment: In a ctor one should prefer using the initializer list instead of an assignment in the ctor body.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED : Could you please give me an example? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Hard to to in a comment, but let me try: `Book::Book() : pointRev(&vectReviews) {}` ...

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: Alright. Thanks for that input. I tried that but it didn't work. Any other suggestions? Maybe I'm doing something wrong else where?

Comment: @blaze: Show the copy-constructor and destructor also.  In fact, showing the entire definition of `Book` would be good, it isn't clear what the lifetime of `vectReviews` is.

Comment: @STATUS : I dont have any destructors yet, and also not sure what a copy constructor is. I know this might show me as stupid but trust me I'm doing the best I can. I'll post the header and cpp file for book.

Comment: @blaze: If you're trying to keep the question from getting really long with so much code, one thing you can do is use links to a separate page (like ideone.com or codepad.com).  Those sites format code nicely and also show line numbers.

Comment: @Ben : Oh ok. I did not know that. Thanks for pointing that out. Will keep that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the behavior you describe, a copy-constructor is running and making two objects that point to the same vector.  `push_back` does indeed use a copy-constructor.

But your first code snippet doesn't make a bunch of copies of the same `Book`, but a new `Book` is created on each loop iteration (and then copied into `vectBooks`.

If `Book` doesn't have a correct user-defined copy-constructor then you aren't managing `pointRev` correctly.  From the observed behavior, I believe that you have a destructor which frees `pointRev`, and then the copy inside `vectBooks` is left with a dangling pointer.  Everything after this falls into the category of *undefined behavior* according to the standard, meaning "anything can happen"  Then the next `Book` happens to reuse the same memory area, so all the instances of `Book` end up with the same value in the wild pointer.  And then updating any one changes the vector (which isn't even alive anymore) seen by all `Book` instances.

Why are you using a pointer to a `std::vector` anyway?  Much better to just put the vector into the class as a direct data member, which lets the compiler construct, copy, and destruct it automatically with no additional help from you.

---

Of course, it's entirely possible that you've made `vectReviews` a global variable, and then every single book points to the same instance.  That would a review show up in all books simultaneously, because they share the vector you're adding it to.

Comment: @Ben : I don't have any destructors setup yet. I didn't really finish coding this project and it slipped my mind for now.  Also, I'm not sure what you meant by why i am using vectors. The driver program doesn't really have a class. Just a main() function that does all the reading from files and then a switch cased menu that present options for manipulation books and reviews. So I am storing these Book objects in a vector declared globally in the driver program and each Book object has a corresponding vector of reviews for storing reviews from multiple users.

Comment: @blazethesinner: Where does `vectBooks` come from?  You're taking its address, but that pointer is only good as long as the original object is alive.

Comment: But anyways, I do not have any destructors set up yet. And could you give an example of a copy constructor? Or what one might look like in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three   And I'm not asking why you're using vectors, I'm asking why your class has a pointer to a vector instead of just having a vector.

Comment: @Ben : to answer your question, it's because it's easier to pass the pointer around than pass the entire vector which I do not know how to do since I would need to pass it by reference the vector is a private member of the class 'Book'.

Comment: @blaze: Surely you could just write `vector<Review>* Book::getReviews() { return &vectReviews; }` and not need the `pointRev` variable.  And then it couldn't possibly end up pointing somewhere weird.  You've done the right thing by making `vectReviews` a member of the class.

Comment: @Ben: So that means the getReviews() function will return a vector? Or dies it return a pointer? Because the return type is of pointer but it's the return statement is returning a vector, I'm confused what's actually being returned. And if it returns a vector, will changes to this returned vector be applied to the one being sent on the other end of the function call?

Comment: @Ben : I tried replacing that return statement with what you stated and it worked. But I still don't understand what happened and changed. Could you please explain? I rather know how it works. Thanks again for the help though!

Comment: @blaze: I don't actually see the code that caused the problem, you have quite a large program apparently.  But something must have called `setPointRev` and associated this book with another book's list of reviews.  See, when you do `setReviews` and say `vectReviews = ...;` it calls vector's assignment operator which makes a copy of the source data.  But when `setPointRev` does `pointRev = ...;` it just copies the pointer, you then have two pointers to the same vector.  And when that vector changed, it affected both books.

Comment: @blaze: Also, the [C++-FAQ Question "Rule of Three"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) does a good job of explaining deep copy vs shallow copy and why you need a copy constructor and destructor (and how to write them) when your class has a pointer inside.

Comment: @Ben: I was reading the rule of 3 document. Kind of in a rush now but will surely finish reading it later. But I think I got the basic point. Also, I didn't notice those set functions. I used my compilers generator for getters and setters so that generated automatically. But I haven't used it once in my code.