# using iterators, ifstream, ofstream the way it's meant to be done

Tags: c++, file-io, coding-style, iterator, fstream

I have a txt file containing a bunch of words, one per line.
I need to read this file and put each word in a list
then the user will be able to modify this list
when done editing, the program will write the modified list in a new file.

Since it's object orinted C++, I'm gonna have two classes, one to read/write to file, and one to edit/mess with the `list<string>` and the user.

With this approach in mind, here's my read function from the first class:

```
bool FileMgr::readToList(list<string> &l)
{
    if(!input.is_open())
        return false;

    string line;
    while(!input.eof())
    {
        getline(input, line);
        l.push_back(line);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Keep in mind: input is opened at constructor.
Questions: is there a less redundant way of getting that damn line from `istream` and pushing it back to `l`? (without the `string` in between).
Questions aside, this function seems to work properly.

Now the output function:

```
bool FileMgr::writeFromList(list<string>::iterator begin,
                            list<string>::iterator end)
{
    ofstream output;
    output.open("output.txt");
    while(begin != end)
    {
        output << *begin << "\n";
        begin++;
    }
    output.close();
    return true;
}
```

This is a portion of my `main`:

```
FileMgr file;
list<string> words;
file.readToList(words);
cout << words.front() << words.back();
list<string>::iterator begin = words.begin();
list<string>::iterator end = words.end();
file.writeFromList(begin, end);
```

Thanks for the help, both functions now work.
Now regarding style, is this a good way to implement these two functions?
Also the `getline(input, line)` part I really don't like, anyone got a better idea?

Comment: Fix the organisation rather than apologising for the lack of it: you have all the time in the world before submitting your question.

Comment: is this a good way to one-line the readToString function?   copy(istream_iterator<string>(input), istream_iterator<string>(), inserter(l, l.end()));

Answer (score 7):

As written, your input loop is incorrect.  The `eof` flag is set *after* a read operation that reaches `eof`, so you could end up going through the loop one too many times.  In addition, you fail to check the `bad` and `fail` flags.  For more information on the flags, what they mean, and how to properly write an input loop, see the Stack Overflow C++ FAQ question [Semantics of flags on `basic_ios`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258887/semantics-of-flags-on-basic-ios).

Your loop in `readToList` should look like this:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(input, line))
{
    l.push_back(line);
}
```

For a more C++ way to do this, see Jerry Coffin's answer to [How do I iterate over `cin` line-by-line in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567082/how-do-i-iterate-over-cin-line-by-line-in-c)  His first solution is quite straightforward and should give you a good idea of how this sort of thing looks in idiomatic, STL-style C++.

For your `writeFromList` function, as Tomalak explains, you need to take two iterators.  When using iterators in C++, you almost always have to use them in pairs:  one pointing to the beginning of the range and one pointing to the end of the range.  It is often preferable as well to use a template parameter for the iterator type so that you can pass different types of iterators to the function; this allows you to swap in different containers as needed.

You don't need to explicitly call `output.close()`:  it is called automatically by the `std::ofstream` destructor.

You can use `std::copy` with `std::ostream_iterator` to turn the output loop into a single line:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
bool FileMgr::writeFromList(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last)
{
    std::ofstream output("output.txt");

    std::copy(first, last, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(output, ""));
}
```

Comment: Jerry Coffin's answer is a perfect example of "how to make your code into cool, modern, C++... and make it disgusting and illegible in the process". Completely unnecessary when this one-line loop body will do the job.

Comment: (Well, ok, his answer covers more than what the one-line loop body does.)

Comment: @Tomalak:  I find the `line` proxy to be very useful.

Comment: Useful sure. Utterly illegible and ultimately unnecessary in most cases? That too.

Answer (score 3):

`writeFromList` should take a start iterator and an end iterator. This range-based approach is what the iterators are designed for, and it's how the stdlib uses them.

So:

```
bool FileMgr::writeFromList(list<string>::iterator it, list<string>::iterator end)
{
    ofstream output("output.txt");

    for (; it != end; ++it)
        output << *it;

    return true;
}
```

and

```
file.writeFromList(words.begin(), words.end());
```

You'll notice I improved your stream usage a little, too.

Ideally `writeFromList` would be generic and take *any* iterator type. But that's future work.

Also note that [your `.eof` is wrong](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5). Do this:

```
string line;
while (getline(input, line))
    l.push_back(line);
```

Comment: thanks, that was really helpful. so somethinf like writeFromList(startIter,endIter) and when i call it it's writeFromList(list.begin(), list.end()), right?

Comment: @Edoz: I never suggested that you should reformat "the whole thing". I pointed out specific points of possible improvement.

Comment: no you were right, it sucked as i posted it. now it's better.