# reading a line in text file twice

Tags: c++

I have this text sample

```
Ahmed 10
kmal 5
doola 6
```

And I am using this code to read it

```
if (myfile.is_open())
{
  while ( myfile.good() )
{

    myfile >> name;
    myfile >> phone;
    cout << name <<" "<<phone<<endl;

}
myfile.close();
```

}

I get this output

```
Ahmed 10
kmal 5
doola 6
doola 6
```

Why does this code read the last line twice ?

Comment: Try `while (myfile.good() && !myfile.eof())`.

Comment: See how to properly use stream flags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258887/semantics-of-flags-on-basic-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
while( myfile >> name >> phone ) {
    // your code here
}
```

I believe the problem with the other approach is that eof isn't signaled until you actually try to read more than you should. That is, when you attempt to `myfile >> name` on the last round. That fails, as does `myfile >> phone` and only then do you break out of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

`myfile.good()` becomes false AFTER the read fails.  Same with `myfile.eof()`.

What you want is basically:

```
myfile >> name;
myfile >> phone;
if (!myfile.good()) break;
```

And this can be shortened to:

```
if (!(myfile >> name >> phone)) break;
```

or finally:

```
while (myfile >> name >> phone) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `while(myfile.good())`. It will still say `true`, even when you have read the last line in your file. And then the next `>>` will fail, leaving the `name` and `phone` variables unchanged from the last input. Use this instead: `while(myfile >> name >> phone) {...}`

Comment: @Ahmed: Ché, I forgot that the same problem exists with `eof()`, sorry. :) Try the new version.

Answer (score 1):

iostream status is not predictive.  It reports the results of the
previous operation, not of the next (which would be impossible to
implement anyway).  *And* myfile.good() isn't even a reliable indicator
of the results of the previous operation: if the operation failed, it
will be false, but if the operation succeeded, it's not necessarily
true.  Forget that function.

Use the fact that the stream can act as a boolean to test success of the
previous operation.  Once you have failure, you can then use eof(),
and bad() to determine why (but with regards to eof(), only after
failure---eof() may return true even if the previous operation
succeeded).  Thus:

```
while ( myfile >> name >> phone ) {
    //  ...
}
if ( myfile.bad() ) {
    std::cerr << "Hardware read error" << std::endl;
} else if ( !myfile.eof() ) {
    std::cerr << "Format error in file" << std::endl;
}
```