# Compiling question math lib c++

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble compiling some code for a class....
this is where i'm having trouble

```
 aavg=0; int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<num;i++)
    {
    if ((math.abs(a[i])<25.0)
    {
 count++;
 aavg+=a[i];                            
     }
     } 
 aavg=aavg/count;
 cout << "The average a value in range, absolute value of a is less than 25.0 is: "<< aavg <<endl;
```

This is my whole program

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    int main (void)
    {
        ifstream input ("measurements");
        int num=0;
        input >> num;
        float a[num];
        float b[num];
        float c[num];
        for(int i=0; i<num;i++)
        input >> a[i] >> b[i] >> c[i];
        //All DATA IN
        //Do A AVERAGE
        float aavg =0;
        for(int i=0; i<num;i++)
        aavg+=a[i]; 
        aavg=aavg/num;
        cout << "A average: " << aavg <<endl;
        //DO SMALLEST B
        float smallb=b[0];
        for(int i=1; i<num; i++)
        if(smallb>b[i])
        smallb=b[i];
        cout <<"Smallest b: " <<smallb <<endl;
        //PRINT ALL GISMO NUMBERS WHERE "a+c<60.0
            for(int i=0; i<num;i++)
            if((a[i]+c[i])<60.0)
         cout <<"Gismo number " <<i <<" has a and c values that total less than 60" <<endl;
        //PRINT SMALLEST C VALUE BETWEEN 25.0 AND 50.0
          float smallc=51;
          for(int i=0; i<num;i++)  
          if((25.0<c[i])&&(c[i]<50))
          if(smallc>c[i])
          smallc=c[i];
          if(smallc>50)
          cout <<"No values in range" <<endl;
          else
          cout <<"Smallest c in range was: "<<smallc <<endl;
          //LAST PART! woot!
          aavg=0; int count=0;
        for(int i=0; i<num;i++)
        {
        if ((math.abs(a[i])<25.0)
        {
     count++;
     aavg+=a[i];                            
         }
         } 
     aavg=aavg/count;
     cout << "The average a value in range, absolute value of a is less than 25.0 is: "<< aavg <<endl;
     //system("PAUSE");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
math.abs
```

`math` is not an object, it's the name of the library.

The function is just `std::abs` (if you include `<cmath>`) or `abs` (if you include `<math.h>`).  You only have to include one of the two headers.

---

Your program has several other problems as well.  The size of an array must be a compile-time constant in C++, so your declarations of `a`, `b`, and `c` are invalid.  The easiest way to do what you are trying to do is to use a `std::vector<float>`.  `std::vector` is a container that can be resized at runtime.

While your program may be okay as a learning exercise, you should always check any input operation to be sure that it succeeded.  If the first thing in your "measurements" file is `Hello`, the first extraction will fail.  `num` will remain `0`, your program won't read any further input, and you will end up dividing by zero (`aavg=aavg/num;`).  You can find out more about the stream error flags and how to correctly check the result of an input operation in [the answers to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258887/semantics-of-flags-on-basic-ios/4259111#4259111).

Comment: Thank you very much. That got it for me. I feel slightly silly. (i'm learning c from another language....and that's how you did abs.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. The one you highlight is the expression:

```
math.abs(a[i])
```

All you want is:

```
fabs(a[i])
```

The other is using  the non-const `num` as an array size. This is not legal. You need dynamically allocated arrays:

```
float* a = new float[num];
```

Comment: Also, count your parenthesis on the line with your 'abs' operation!

Comment: Note that in C++, `abs` works with floating point arguments and since this is C++, `std::vector` is preferable to manual dynamic allocation of arrays.