# Why Ctrl-Z does not trigger EOF?

Tags: c, visual-c++, eof, getchar

Why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does not trigger the loop to finish on the following small program?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        //nothing 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I enter: `test^ZEnter`, it does not get out of the loop.

I found related questions around ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655112/why-do-i-require-multiple-eof-ctrlz-characters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378899/why-doesnt-the-eof-character-work-if-put-at-the-end-of-a-line)) but none to explain it for C (not C++) under Windows.

**Note**: I use Visual Studio 2015 PRE on a windows 8.1

Comment: @ARBY , CTRL+C doesn't send `EOF`, right?

Comment: @CoolGuy  Oh sorry, I meant ctrl+D as in *nix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782080/what-is-eof-in-the-c-programming-language

Comment: This link might help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378899/why-doesnt-the-eof-character-work-if-put-at-the-end-of-a-line)

Comment: @ARBY I knew about that post (see initial question) but is not very clear

Comment: @ARBY Isn't that the same link provided in this question?

Comment: @Alex Your problem is clearly explained in [the first link you provide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655112/why-do-i-require-multiple-eof-ctrlz-characters). In short, since there are characters to be flushed into the stdin, CTRL+Z and enter flushes those characters instead of sending EOF. In other words, CTRL+Z (windows, DOS) and CTRL+D (Linux, Unix, OSX etc) send EOF **if there are no more characters to be flushed to the `stdin`.**

Comment: @CoolGuy Thanks, you should post that as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

or, you may also use <kbd>F6</kbd>

Answer (score -4):

`EOF` like you use it is not a character. It's the status in which that stream is.

I mean, heck, you even link this question, so you might as well [read the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5657206/4433386):

> The underlying form of an EOF is a zero-length read.

It's not an "EOF character".

http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/getcharc.html cites a different case than yours, where someone stored the return value of `getchar` in a `char`. The underlying problem still occurs occasionally: different runtimes implement different values for the `EOF` *integer* (which is why I said, it's not an EOF *character*), and things love to go wrong. Especially in Visual C++, which is not a "real" C compiler but a C++ compiler with a compatibility mode, it seems things can go wrong.

Comment: So why does Ctrl+Z not trigger "the status in which that stream is" to EOF?

Comment: it probably does, but you're not checking for that.

Comment: How does one check for it with getchar() then?

Comment: That's like asking "how do I mine for fish".

Comment: Apparently [people like to do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720821/im-trying-to-understand-getchar-eof).

Comment: That's really really old legacy behaviour. I recommend going the standard compliant rout of checking whether `feof(stdin)` returns true.

Comment: Funny, [this man page also likes to mine for fish](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar). Please provide a "non legacy" reference for getchar/getc.

Comment: @user2864740: You're right, but read that function prototype very closely! What's the return type? It's an int, and I think that's the case exactly because they wanted to be able to read chars or return errors. Now, what they did is take the EOF for all errors and end-of-file. Using EOF to check against end-of-file has been frowned upon for quite a while. I'll add a reference.

Comment: The problem in the cited case is using `char` as the variable; the posted code uses `int`, correctly, which can detect the EOF "out-of-band" state.