# Why EOF is not working in the same way?

Tags: c, windows

```
#include <stdio.h>  

main(){ 
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    while (c!= EOF) 
    {
        putchar(c); 
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
1. Output: Hi there ^Z? 

           Hi there ->_ (loop doesn't end)
2. Output: Hi there?

           Hi there?
           ^Z (loop ends)
```

Why doesn't the loop end in the first case after reading ^Z but it ends in the second case?

Comment: You're mixing up ^Z with the end-of-file condition. Pressing ^Z during a line causes the current line to be flushed and nothing more. Pressing it again causes end-of-file status to be set on the stream .

Comment: With ^Z, I would expect SIGTSTP to go to the process and that it would be backgrounded.  I think you need a windows tag.

Comment: I read answers of  Why do I require multiple EOF (CTRL+Z) characters? but I didn't get anything. I am new to programming and I also didn't understand any of the above explanations. :(

Comment: Perhaps [this will make you understand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261483/why-ctrl-z-does-not-trigger-eof?lq=1#comment50520540_31261483)

Comment: Thank you for all the answers!